# Does scikit-learn use One-Vs-Rest by default in multi-class classification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification

I am dealing with a multi-class problem (4 classes) and I am trying to solve it with scikit-learn in Python.

I saw that I have three options:

1. I simply instantiate a classifier, then I fit with train and evaluate with test;

   ```
   classifier = sv.LinearSVC(random_state=123)
   classifier.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)
   classifier.score(Xtest, ytest)
   ```
2. I "encapsulate" the instantiated classifier in a OneVsRest object, generating a new classifier that I use for train and test;

   ```
   classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(svm.LinearSVC(random_state=123))
   classifier.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)
   classifier.score(Xtest, ytest)
   ```
3. I "encapsulate" the instantiated classifier in a OneVsOne object, generating a new classifier that I use for train and test.

   ```
   classifier = OneVsOneClassifier(svm.LinearSVC(random_state=123))
   classifier.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)
   classifier.score(Xtest, ytest)
   ```

I understand the difference between OneVsRest and OneVsOne, but I cannot understand what I am doing in the first scenario where I do not explicitly pick up any of these two options. What does scikit-learn do in that case? Does it implicitly use OneVsRest?

Any clarification on the matter would be highly appreciated.

Best, 
MR

**Edit**:
Just to make things clear, I am not specifically interested in the case of SVMs. For example, what about RandomForest?

Comment: Please *format* your code

Comment: You're right. I did it many times and somehow the code formatting was not working, so I eventually gave up.

Comment: Essentially explained in the scikit-learn docs: [Multiclass and multilabel algorithms](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated answer**: As clarified in the comments and edits, the question is more about the general setting of sklearn, and less about the specific case of `LinearSVC` which is explained below.

The main difference here is that some of the classifiers you can use have "built-in multiclass classification support", i.e. it is possible for that algorithm to discern between more than two classes *by default*. One example for this would for example be a Random Forest, or a Multi-Layer Perceptron (MLP) with multiple output nodes.

In these cases, having a `OneVs` object is not required at all, since you are already solving your task. In fact, using such a strategie might even decreaes your performance, since you are "hiding" potential correlations from the algorithm, by letting it only decide between single binary instances.

On the other hand, algorithms like `SVC` or `LinearSVC` only support *binary* classification. So, to extend these classes of (well-performing) algorithms, we instead have to rely on the reduction to a binary classification task, from our initial multiclass classification task.

As far as I am aware of, the most complete overview can be found [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html):
If you scroll down a little bit, you can see which one of the algorithms is inherently multiclass, or uses either one of the strategies by default. 
**Note that all of the listed algorithms under OVO actually now employ a OVR strategy by default!** This seems to be slightly outdated information in that regard.

**Initial answer**:

This is a question that can easily be answered by looking at [the relevant scikit-learn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html). 
Generally, the expectation on Stackoverflow is that you have at least done some form of research on your own, so please consider looking into existing documentation first.

> **multi_class** : string, ‘ovr’ or ‘crammer_singer’ (default=’ovr’)
>
> Determines the multi-class strategy if y contains more than two classes. `"ovr"` trains n_classes one-vs-rest classifiers, while
>   `"crammer_singer"` optimizes a joint objective over all classes. While
>   crammer_singer is interesting from a theoretical perspective as it is
>   consistent, it is seldom used in practice as it rarely leads to better
>   accuracy and is more expensive to compute. If `"crammer_singer"` is
>   chosen, the options loss, penalty and dual will be ignored.

So, clearly, it uses one-vs-rest.

The same holds by the way for the "regular" [SVC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC).

Comment: Let me thank you for your quick reply, but let me also tell you I do not like this attitude. I did prior research and I could not find the information. Indeed, although I put svm in the example I was working with RandomForest and I do not see that parameter for RF. What's the answer then?

Comment: @rusiano the answer is correct as far as your original question is concerned. Changing the question *after* an answer has been provided is far from good practice; please accept the answer and open a different question if you still have issues.

Comment: I never said I am interested in knowing explicitly about SVM.  The question still remains, it's just your answer that is partial.

Comment: @rusiano 1) "but I cannot understand what I am doing in the first scenario [...] What does scikit-learn do in that case?" - your first scenario explicitly involves SVM 2) please, try to argue in a **productive** way (we all do mistakes, the point is not to pointlessly defend them), and remember that people here are *voluntarily* trying to help 3) consider me a third-party observer (the answer is *not mine*)...

Comment: To chime in here: I understood it with the SVM case as well, so thanks for clearing that up. I'm currently looking into how I can best explain the concept of OVO/OVR in this (more general) context, so I'll update the answer hopefully in a little while. My harsh response with regards to the search is that it seemed to me as it was literally just looking it up for SVM; in a more general context, I consider this a more accurate and relevant question.